# How to correct this solder?

Tags: soldering

I have repaired this circuit from a fridge but the soldering that I have marked in red seems to have pulled away from the copper track. That is because when I tried to replace the capacitor that was there, I had to pull and that was the problem. I have almost cut the track.

The circuit is now working, but I don't know if I can repair this in some way.

[image: bad solder]

Comment: So the track is partially lifted? And you're hoping for a method to stick it back onto the board? (I don't know of any method to do that, personally).

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here but typically damaged tracks would be bypassed with wire or perhaps tinned sheet stock.  Don't neglect voltage concerns especially in something that may operate in a moist environment.

Comment: Thank you @DKNguyen! Yes, it´s partially lifted. I have solder the tiny part that is still attached to the PCB...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that any components that are attached to the pad are attached to the board in a mechanically sound manner.  A little dot of epoxy glue or hot glue should do.  You'll have to use your judgement.

Then make sure that the trace has enough copper to carry the current it used to.  Use your judgement -- usually this is repaired with a bit of bare wire, or copper foil.

If it won't move, and it won't burn up, you're done.